# Regex to ignore trailing dot if there is one

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following regex (crudely matching things that look like URLS)

```
(https?://\S*)
```

However, this is to pull out URLs in sentences, so trailing dots are *probably* end of sentences rather than legitimate parts of the URL.

What's the magic incantation to get the capture group to ignore trailing full stops, commas, colons, semi-colons etc?

(I know that matching URLs is a nightmare, this only needs to support matching them loosely, hence the very simple regex)

Here's my test string:

```
lorem http://www.example.com lorem https://example.com lorem 
http://www.example.com.
lorem https://example.com.
```

This should match all the example.com instances.

(I'm testing it with Expresso and .NET)

Test result with trailing dot and new line:

```
  Expected string length 62 but was 64. Strings differ at index 31.
  Expected: "<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>.\n\r"
  But was:  "<a href="http://www.example.com.\n">http://www.example.com.\n</a>\r"
  ------------------------------------------^
```

**Example Code**

```
public class HyperlinkParser
{
    private readonly Regex _regex =
        new Regex(
            @"(https?://\S*[^\.])");

    public string Parse(string original)
    {
        var parsed = _regex.Replace(original, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
        return parsed;
    }
}
```

**Example Tests**

```
[TestFixture]
public class HyperlinkParserTests
{
    private readonly HyperlinkParser _parser = new HyperlinkParser();
    private const string NO_HYPERLINKS = "dummy-text";
    private const string FULL_URL = "http://www.example.com";
    private const string FULL_URL_PARSED = "<a href=\"" + FULL_URL + "\">" + FULL_URL + "</a>";
    private const string FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT = FULL_URL + ".";
    private const string FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT_PARSED = "<a href=\"" + FULL_URL + "\">" + FULL_URL + "</a>.";
    private const string TRAILING_DOT_AND_NEW_LINE = FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT + "\n\r";
    private const string TRAILING_DOT_AND_NEW_LINE_PARSED = FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT_PARSED + "\n\r";

    private const string COMPLEX_TEXT = "Leading stuff http://www.example.com.  Other stuff.";
    private const string COMPLEX_TEXT_PARSED = "Leading stuff <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">http://www.example.com</a>.  Other stuff.";

    [TestCase(NO_HYPERLINKS, NO_HYPERLINKS)]
    [TestCase(FULL_URL, FULL_URL_PARSED)]
    [TestCase(FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT, FULL_URL_TRAILING_DOT_PARSED)]
    [TestCase(TRAILING_DOT_AND_NEW_LINE, TRAILING_DOT_AND_NEW_LINE_PARSED)]
    [TestCase(COMPLEX_TEXT, COMPLEX_TEXT_PARSED)]
    public void Parsing(string original, string expected)
    {
        var actual = _parser.Parse(original);

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a test code? A fiddle on, say, [IDEONE.com](http://ideone.com) would be very helpful. Testing strings with whitespace is not an easy thing, we may test on a string different from yours.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've added the code, I can't get the parsing to work on the online fiddles.  I have got this working successfully by using `[^\W]` in placve of `[^\.]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it forbids the dot as the last character:

```
(https?://\S*[^.])
```

E.g. under cygwin, with egrep:

```
$ cat ~/tmp.txt
lorem http://www.example.com lorem https://example.com lorem
http://www.example.com.
lorem https://example.com.
$ cat ~/tmp.txt | egrep -o 'https?://\S*[^.]'
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

(The `-o` option tells egrep to print only matches.)

Comment: For some reason, this now matches `http://www.example.com.[CR]` (CR = carriage return)

Comment: Did you also mean to type `[^\.]`?

Comment: Why do I get it capturing both the dot and a new line too then?  This is odd.  I'm using the .NET implementation, if that means anything.

Comment: I don't what is wrong with your envirnment, but according to this it should work with .NET as well: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(https%3f%3a%2f%2f%5cS*%5b%5e.%5d)&i=lorem+http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com+lorem+https%3a%2f%2fexample.com+lorem+%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com.%0d%0alorem+https%3a%2f%2fexample.com.

Comment: Have a look at the second match, it is picking up the dot and (I suspect) the new line too.  The new line seems to do something.

Comment: You can see it clearer when replacing:  [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(https%3f%3a%2f%2f%5cS*%5b%5e.%5d)&i=lorem+http%253%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8ba%2f%2fwww.example.com+lorem+https%3a%2f%2fexample.com+lorem+%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fw%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8bww.example.com.%0d%0alorem+https%3a%2f%2fexample.com&r=!%241%5c!)